# Why isn't the arrow displayed when I use Show?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have been trying to combine two plots using `Show`. Everything looks fine, but the arrow from one of the plots does not show. What am I doing wrong here?

```
qw = 
  Plot[y /. Solve[(x/20)^2 + (y/10)^2 == 1], {x, -36, 35}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{-37, 35}, {-16, 16}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor["#123c69"]}, 
    Ticks -> Automatic, 
    Axes -> True];

Aq = 
  Plot[-a/((x^4)) - b, {x, -21, -35}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-36, -21}, {-6.5, -9.5}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor["#ac3b61"]}, 
    Epilog -> 
      {RGBColor["#ac3b61"], 
       Arrow[{{-35, -((3151 Sqrt[7])/1250)}, {-35.7, -6.640033236810056}}]}];

Show[qw, Aq]
```

Comment: Use `Show[qw, Aq, Epilog -> ...]` instead of putting the `Epilog` inside of the second `Plot` function.

Answer (score 2):

The options are always taken from the first object in `Show`. For example, you've specified `PlotRange` for both but the one that's being used with `Show` is the first one. It works like this for all options, including `Epilog`. You'll see the arrow if you change the order:

```
Show[Aq, qw]
```

but then, of course, the plot range will not be the same anymore. That's why it is sometimes necessary or useful to supply options to `Show`, which overrides the options given by the first argument. In this case,

```
Show[qw, Aq, 
 Epilog -> {RGBColor["#ac3b61"], 
   Arrow[{{-35, -((3151 Sqrt[7])/
         1250)}, {-35.7, -6.640033236810056}}]}]
```

shoud do it, as Carl noted in a comment.